# Visual Studio 2013 MVC4 Incompatible Project Type

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I can't open a visual studio project on one particular machine, I get the error "The application which this project type is based on was not found".

After hours of searching and trying various things like re-installing MVC4, ASP.Net 4.5 and WebTools, as well as running "devenv /setup" in the vs command prompt - I still cannot get this to work.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate running as administrator and oddly enough when I remove the MVC4 guid (E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47) from the ProjectTypeGuids in the projects csproj file, it works fine which seems to suggest that I do have all the pre-requisite components for the project but they're not being recognised for some reason.

I have 2 questions:

1. Can I fix this issue without having to delete the ProjectTypeGuid from the csproj?
2. If not, will removing this guid cause any further issues?

Comment: It is a pretty serious problem, strongly suggesting that your registry is borken.  You can have a look-see with Regedit.exe at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Projects\{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47}, the key where the package is registered.

Comment: @HansPassant that project type guid is indeed missing from the registry - is there a way to add it in or am I looking at a full re-install (trying to avoid that as it takes a long time on my rural internet connection from MSDN).

Comment: No.  You'll have to dig through the setup *.log files left behind in your TEMP directory to get a hint why the package was skipped.  Download the ISO so you don't have to wait repeatedly.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks, can you add your comment as an answer so I can mark it complete please.

Comment: It is not an answer.  Only you know how you fixed it, just tells us about it in your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-installing did not fix the problem however after [forcibly removing Visual Studio](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2771441/EN-US#Force) and installing again, the issue seems to have resolved itself.

Answer (score 2):

For me, running the installer again showed that somehow the web tools had been uninstalled, checking the box to install them again fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

To fix problem you can just add missing key to registry. Below is content of '.reg' file which I gained exported the value of 'E3‌​E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47' key from not broken registry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Projects\{E3E379DF-

F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47}]
@="Web MVC Project Factory"
"Package"="{141DA93E-88A7-45D5-B15B-89117F514D64}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Projects\{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47}\LanguageTemplates]
"{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}"="{2F6AD3CD-6215-4895-B241-CE606A2491CD}"
"{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}"="{162F00EC-2232-4771-B72F-6BBFB0F7DCC1}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after updating to Visual Studio 2015 Update 1.

My steps to resolve:

1. Close VS 2015 if open
2. Open up Add/Remove Programs
3. Right click `Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015` in the list and click Change
4. In the installer window, click Modify
5. Under `Windows and Web Development` ensure the checkbox is checked. If it isn't (as for me), check it.
6. Hit the UPDATE button in the bottom right of the installer
7. After the installation process completes, open your solution and it should all be working.

If all else fails, here is my VS2015 registry key as per the other answer which may be helpful:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Projects\{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47}]
@="Web MVC 4 Project Factory (Compatibility)"
"Package"="{141DA93E-88A7-45D5-B15B-89117F514D64}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Projects\{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47}\LanguageTemplates]
"{FAE04EC0-4F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}"="{2F6AD3CD-6215-4895-B241-CE606A2491CD}"
"{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}"="{162F00EC-2232-4771-B72F-6BBFB0F7DCC1}"
"{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}"="{2F6AD3CD-6215-4895-B241-CE606A2491CD}"
```